# (Un)distorted subgroups in $\mathbb{F}_2 \times \mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, computational-algebra

We consider the product of free groups $$\mathbb{F}_2 \times \mathbb{F}_2 = \langle a,b,c,d \mid [a,b]=[b,c]=[c,d]=[d,a]=1 \rangle.$$ Given some elements $g_1,\ldots,g_n \in \mathbb{F}_2 \times \mathbb{F}_2$, viewed as words over $\{a,b,c,d \}^{\pm 1}$, is there an algorithm to determine if the subgroup $\langle g_1, \ldots,g_n \rangle$ is undistorted (ie. the inclusion induces a quasi-isometric embedding)?

For instance, for an explicit example, is the subgroup $\langle a,b,cd \rangle$ undistorted?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $[a,b]=1$?  The elements of $\mathbb F_2\times\mathbb F_2$ should be pairs.  It's a bit confusing.

Comment: Here, $[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ so that $[a,b]=1$ means that $a$ and $b$ commute.

Comment: In the presentation I give, the group splits as $\langle a,c \rangle \times \langle b,d \rangle$. In the same way, I could write $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} = \langle a,b \mid [a,b]=1 \rangle$.

Comment: OK I understand what you mean by square brackets now.  Now by pointy brackets do you mean "the subgroup generated by"?

Comment: This might be a suitable question for mathoverflow. It is possible that the problem is undecidable. There are algorithms that verify whether a subgroup is quasiconvex (i.e. they cannot decide quasiconvexity but they can confirm it). I think quasiconvex subgroups are quasi-isometrically embedded, but I am not sure about the converse.

Comment: Your example is not quasiconvex, because the geodesic word $c^nd^n$ lies in the subgroup (it equals $(cd)^n$, but does not stay within a bounded neighborhood of the subgroup. But I would guess that it is undistorted.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: Absolutely.

Comment: @DerekHolt: In fact, I have a sketch of proof that $\langle a,b,cd \rangle$ is an undistorted subgroup, but the argument is really specific to this subgroup, if I change a little the generators, I lose the proof. So I was curious to know whether there exist more "systematic" methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be the projections of $H$ on both factors, and $I_1,I_2$ the intersections; then $P_1/I_1\simeq P_2/I_2$, call this group $Q$. Then

> $H$ is undistorted in $\mathbf{F}_2\times\mathbf{F}_2$ if and only if $Q$ is word-hyperbolic

(it's due to Olshanskii and Sapir, see the [discussion here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107192/dehn-function-for-undistorted-subgroups-of-a-product-of-free-groups)). Since word-hyperbolicity is not decidable for finite presentations of 2-generator groups, *it follows that the problem whether a subgroup given by inputting finitely generators is undistorted is undecidable*. Precisely, if $P=\langle x,y\mid w_i(x,y):i\in I\rangle$ is a finite presentation defining a group $\Gamma_P$, consider the subgroup $H_P$ of $F_2\times F_2$ (where $F_2=\langle x,y\rangle$) generated by $(x,x)$, $(y,y)$, and $(w_i(x,y),1)$, $i\in I$. Then $H_P$ is undistorted iff $\Gamma_P$ is word-hyperbolic.

However it is quite a practical criterion. In the example you provide, using my notation you have the subgroup generated by $(x,1)$, $(1,x)$, $(y,y)$; it corresponds to the presentation $\langle x,y\mid x\rangle$ of the infinite cyclic group, which is definitely word-hyperbolic, and this is consistent with the fact you can check that your group is undistorted.

Comment: It is a nice result, thank you!